# Why can't I import my module into my main code?

Tags: python, function, module

I wrote some code (named exercise 2) where I define a function (named is_divisible) and it has worked perfectly.

Afterwards to learn how to import functions, I wrote the same code but without the defined function, and created a second module (named is_divisible). But whenever I import this module into the original "exercise 2" I get

*No module named 'is_divisible'*

I have checked that both python files are in the same folder, the name of the file is correct, and I know the code is well written because it has worked before and it is from a lecturer's of mine. I have also attempted to name the module and the function differently and to instead write:

```
from divis import is_divisible
```

but this was also unsuccessful.

**Where am I going wrong?** I will leave the code below:

```
import random
import math
import numpy as np

random_list=[]

for i in range (0,5):
    r=random.randint(0,10)
    random_list.append(r)

print(random_list) #five numbers from 0 to 10 are chosen and appended to a list


new_result=[print('right' for x in random_list if round(np.cosh(x)**2 - np.sinh(x)**2,2) == 1] 
#checking the numbers following a maths rule

import is_divisible  #trying to import the function is_divisible

divisor=3 
idx = is_divisible(random_list, divisor)
for i in idx:
    print(f'Value {random_list[i]} (at index {i}) is divisible by {divisor}')
```

the code for the function *is_divisible* is:

```
def is_divisible(x, n):
""" Find the indices of x where the element is exactly divisible by n.

Arguments:
x - list of numbers to test
n - single divisor

Returns a list of the indices of x for which the value of the element is
divisible by n (to a precision of 1e-6 in the case of floats).

Example:
>>> is_divisible([3, 1, 3.1415, 6, 7.5], 3)
[0, 3]

"""

r = []
small = 1e-6
for i, m in enumerate(x):
    if m % n < small:
        r.append(i)
return r
```

I know this question has been answered multiple times, but none of the answers seem to work for me or maybe I am not doing it correctly.

Comment: Is your indentation correct for is_divisible function? and instead of new_result=[print('right' for x in random_list if round(np.cosh(x)**2 - np.sinh(x)**2,2) == 1] it should be new_result=print('right' for x in random_list if round(np.cosh(x)**2 - np.sinh(x)**2,2) == 1)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the indentation seems to be fine, it is just as shown above, no spaces whatsoever. And thank you for the second bit of information, that makes that bit work better (although it should not influence the rest of the code)

Comment: You need to provide more information about the structure of your files/directories, otherwise it is impossible to help you.. Could it be that perhaps both files/modules are located inside a package? Ie. a folder which contains an "\_\_init__.py" file? If so you would need to do "from <PACKAGE-NAME>.divis import is_divisible", unless you have installed the package, which I am assuming that you haven't done..

Comment: I have come across the "__init__.py" file but I don't seem to understand it. I have been using python for a while, but simply for plotting and analysis of data and this is all very new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you type `import <Module>` the module is the name of the file. So, if you had the function `is_divisible` inside a Python file named `a.py`, then to import it you will write `from a import is_divisible`. If instead, you would like to import the whole file, then you'd write `import a.py`, then to use the function you would use `a.is_divisible(random_list, divisor)`.

You should also make sure that both files are in the same folder.

Comment: Hello Talbi. The problem is both files are in the same folder and the function is_divisible is also the name of the file. I have attempted giving it a different name and do as you said, but it did not work.